# Confusion regarding WCF at Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, deployment

I have few `WCF` services, deployed at `IIS`, which are consumed by some `android` devices. I'm have to move all my databases and services to `Azure`. I googled to find out how to deploy `WCF` at `Azure`, and found a concept of `WebRole` and `Azure Cloud Service` project. See [THIS SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838435/deploying-wcf-service-on-windows-azure)

But at the same time, I just tried creating a new `webapp` in `Azure` and simply published my `WCF` services project there, and it worked fine. (I tested with client).

My Question is,

- What is the difference between the methods mentioned in the post I linked, and the way I deployed? I'm concerned, because I'm expecting high amount of requests.
- Is it okay to deploy my already created/ready services the way I did?
- What is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both (WebApp and Web role) will work for your scenario.

The main difference between this two way is that Web role allows you to connect to it through remote desktop.

You can keep using WebApp and configure Auto Scaling (based on CPU usage or at a specific time).

Comment: thank you. Does this mean, a VM is setup against WebRole?

Comment: @Zeeshan yes, webrole is a vm that you can connect to it.