# Where to host WCF service for CRM Online 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I have created a WCF service, which will be consumed by / called from `CRM 2016 Online Case Form` (using jscript/ajax call).

Where should I host the WCF service?

Comment: try perhaps the superuser.com site.

Answer (score 0):

You are responsible for deciding where to host the service and configuring/programming for single sign-on (if you need security and want to avoid additional password prompts.)

The most logical place to run this would be in Azure: [Deploying WCF Service on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838435/deploying-wcf-service-on-windows-azure)