# Migrating windows service hosted TCP WCF service to windows azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, tcp, windows-services

We have requirement to migrate a TCP WCF Service which is hosted as Windows Service in an on-premise environment to windows azure.

I know, we can go with IaaS(Infrastructure as a Service) in windows azure and host the application in some Azure Virtual Machine and work the same way it was working in on-premise. I am curious to know, if there can be any options available with PaaS (Platform as a Service) or SaaS (Software as a Service) features of windows azure upon this requirement.

Comment: Seems a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838435/deploying-wcf-service-on-windows-azure, check [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nishasingh/2012/12/04/creating-and-deploying-a-wcf-service-on-windows-azure-and-consuming-it-in-windows-8-store-app/) and [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-create-and-host-WCF-services-in-Azure) for more details.

Comment: Solution uses Web role and I assume Web Role can be corelated with WCF Service hosted in IIS. But my requirement is to deploy WCF Service as Windows Service in Azure. Can it be kind of worker role?